# Error while using part="...,processingDetails" in a youtube.videos.insert() request

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, java-7, youtube-data-api

We're developing in java 7 and YouTube Data API v3.

When we are calling the upload service with "processingDetails" part, we are getting a 503 Service Unavailable Error.   What are we doing wrong?  If we remove it, we can upload the video just fine.  But we want/need to know about processingDetails.

Here is the code:

```
YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = this.youtube.videos().insert("snippet,statistics,status,processingDetails", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);
```

everything else it's the same as the java client provided in google API.

Here is the request:
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,statistics,status,processingDetails

And here is the exception stack trace:

> 2013-06-14 17:50:40,375 ERROR [] [main] (...)despegar.client.impl.YouTubeMediaClient (YouTubeMediaClient.java:264) : Error
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:111)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:38)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
>       at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
>       at com.despegar.client.impl.YouTubeMediaClient.uploadVideoWithFailureRecovery(YouTubeMediaClient.java:285)
>       at com.despegar.client.impl.YouTubeMediaClient.uploadAttempt(YouTubeMediaClient.java:260)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. The `part` parameter values you include in your `youtube.videos.insert()` request should correspond to the parts you're specifying in the upload metadata. Normally this would be `snippet` (since that's the part containing the required title and description) and sometimes `status` (if you're also setting the public/private status of the video). You can't set `statistics` or `processingDetails` during an upload, so you shouldn't include them in the list of parts. You can still request the `statistics` or `processingDetails` parts *after* the upload completes, via a `youtube.videos.list()` call.
2. The API should return a meaningful error message explaining this to you instead of returning a generic 503. I'll file a bug with the engineering team asking them to take care of that.

Comment: Shouldn't the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) be clearer then? I find it misleading, as it lists `processingDetails` as one of the valid options for `parts` during a `videos.insert()`. Is this a mistake in the docs?

Comment: Yes, this is also a case of misleading documentation. I'll ping the technical writing team about that.