# Unable to get processing details for youtube video upload

Tags: python, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've followed the documentation for uploading a video to Youtube using Youtube's v3 data api.

I'm able to upload the video succesfully but I need to know if the video has finished processing, in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#parameters) it says that I can pass 
`processingDetails` as part of the `parts` parameter and this should give me back the processing details but I keep getting a 400 error, I saw someone had the same issue 2-3 years ago and asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17117436/error-while-using-part-processingdetails-in-a-youtube-videos-insert-requ), so I'd like to confirm if this is still just a documentation problem or I'm I calling this incorrectly?

```
POST /upload/youtube/v3/videos?uploadType=resumable&part=id,snippet,processingDetails,status HTTP/1.1" 400
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are referencing is a known issue involving `youtube.videos.insert()` and `processingDetails` that has been reported to the Google team [here](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8027&thanks=8027&ts=1456092630).

There is also a related extant [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6493&q=processing&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary) regarding `processingDetails.processingProgress` for `youtube.videos().list`.

In the meantime, what worked for me was to upload a video and then call `youtube.videos.list()` including `processingDetails` as a parameter.  I got this result, for example, immediately after an upload:

```
    "processingDetails": {
        "processingStatus": "succeeded",
        "fileDetailsAvailability": "available",
        "processingIssuesAvailability": "available",
        "tagSuggestionsAvailability": "available",
        "editorSuggestionsAvailability": "available",
        "thumbnailsAvailability": "inProgress"
    }
```

Here are additional [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#processingDetails) on `processingDetails`.